# Microsoft Edge "Permission Denied" Issue When Setting "document.domain" in Dynamically Created IFrame

Tags: iframe, permission-denied, microsoft-edge

Any idea why the script below will return "SCRIPT70: Permission denied" in Windows 10 Microsoft Edge browser?

```
var f= document.createElement("iframe");
f.src = "javascript:void((function(){document.open();document.domain=document.domain;document.close();})())";
document.body.appendChild(f);
```

Please note that this script is working in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain, but could be because the `javascript:` URI is not supported in Edge